# Composer BowerPHP Error

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am trying to install BowerPHP in my Laravel framework project on my computer using Composer. I have used the `composer require "beelab/bowerphp 0.3.*@beta"` command in the command prompt but I'm receiving errors:

```
Can only install one of : symfony/process[v2.7.9,v3.0.2]
Can only install one of : symfony/process[v2.7.8,v3.0.2]
Can only install one of : symfony/process[v2.7.7,v3.0.2]
```

etc.

From what I understand my framework already has a version of Symfony and I cannot download another package. In addition, the package that I have is not compatible with BowerPHP. What do I do? And am I correct?

Comment: Seems it clashes with `symfony/process`. Give `beelab/bowerphp` `dev-master` a try. The dev-master branch has a requirement for symfony/process with `~2.3|~3.0` - so the 3.0.x version should hopefully resolve.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer. The beelab team did not update their own website but did update their github page. running the composer `require beelab/bowerphp:1.0.*@dev`  would work but running the on on their website would not.